# Invoke AuthorizationHandler in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, webapi

In an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, I'm trying to invoke an `AuthorizationHandler` function. I want to create an authorization mechanism that first will authenticate the user from AWS cognito with [Authorize] tag  - this part is working.

After that, I want my own custom authorization mechanism.

My problem is that the `AuthorizationHandler` function is not invoked.

This are the parts from my code:

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("ScreenAuthorizationPolicy", policy =>
    {
        policy.Requirements.Add(new ScreenAuthorizationRequirement());
    });
});
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, ScreenAuthorizationHandler>();
.
.
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();


app.MapControllers();
app.UseCors("*");
app.Run();
```

**AuthorizationAttribute.cs**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class ScreenAuthorizationAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public Screens ScreenID { get; }
        public PermissionLevel PermissionLevel { get; }

        public ScreenAuthorizationAttribute(Screens screenID, PermissionLevel permissionLevel)
        {
            ScreenID = screenID;
            PermissionLevel = permissionLevel;
        }
    }
```

**ScreenAuthorizationRequirement.cs**

```
public class ScreenAuthorizationRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
    {
    }
```

**ScreenAuthorizationHandler.cs**

```
public class ScreenAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ScreenAuthorizationRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
        AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
        ScreenAuthorizationRequirement requirement)
    {
        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

This is the function I need to get into.

In my controller I'm writing

```
 [Route("api/[controller]/Endpoint")]
 [Authorize]
 [ScreenAuthorization(Screens.screen1, PermissionLevel.Read)]
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetSomething()
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may confuse the usage of the two authorization policies.

**The first one:** [Policy-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

use a requirement, a requirement handler, and a preconfigured policy.

Apply policies to controllers by using the `[Authorize]` attribute with the policy name. For example:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "AtLeast21")]
public class AtLeast21Controller : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index() => View();
}
```

**The second one:** [Custom Authorization attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-6.0#custom-authorization-attributes)

deriving from AuthorizeAttribute, and use a custom IAuthorizationPolicyProvider to control how authorization policies are supplied.

You can apply it to actions in the same way as other Authorize attributes.For example:

```
[MinimumAgeAuthorize(10)]
public IActionResult RequiresMinimumAge10()
```

Comment: There’s much better support for this coming in .NET 8 https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-8-preview-4/#improved-support-for-custom-authorization-policies-with-iauthorizationrequirementdata

Comment: My mistake is deriving from Attribute and not from AuthorizeAttribute 
And know it works well. 
I'm receiving the params in the handler from the context.
Fill free to use it :-) .